# Null Pointer on springSecurityService.currentUser

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-3.0

Using spring security plugin 3.0.0 (`spring-security-core:3.0.0.M1`) and Grails 3.0.6 I get a `NullPointerException` trying to get some properties on `springSecurityService` object according to latest documentation.

`springSecurityService` is successfully instantiated, but it hasn't these properties:

```
springSecurityService.currentUser
springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
springSecurityService.loadCurrentUser()
```

But following is OK

```
springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()
springSecurityService.authentication 
springSecurityService.getAuthentication()
```

My controller code:

```
class TestController {

   def springSecurityService

   def index() {

        CurrentUser currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser

        render "hallo"
    }
}
```

What is wrong here?

UPDATE: I used wrong UserDeatailsService, when I rewtited it the problem has gone.

Comment: That's pretty weird - those methods are certainly there in the source. What is printed if you add `println springSecurityService.getClass().name` in a controller action?

Comment: result is "grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService"

Comment: @AlexShwarc I also encountered same error and spent one whole day. i don't know what is your environment, but mine was coming if I rung Application.groovy from Intellij. If I use Gradle:run task, it does not appear. You can see my sample app which is using springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()  method in a service which gets injected into my domain classes and I don't have any problem with it as long as I use Gradle:run or grails run-app. Application.groovy version has  NPE.

Comment: I solved a problem, it was wrong implementation of custom UserDetailsService.

Comment: It seems that `springSecurityService.currentUser` expects the user object to be provided by gorm.  If you are not using gorm you will generally get null pointers using this.